# Chrome animated gif background-image not playing - background-size

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animated-gif

I'm trying to display a thumbnail button with an animated gif as background image. But only in chrome, the gif is not looped.

FF and Edge are working fine?!

When playing with the background-size in chrome dev tools, the gif start looping at a certain %.

HTML

```
<span class="thumbnail"></span>
```

CSS

```
.thumbnail {
    background-position: -12px -14px;
    background-size: 150%;
    background-color: rgb(250, 252, 252);
    background-image: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/xTiTnxd70rHICWIQSs/giphy.gif);
    ...
}
```

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tomvanrossom/hL2boada/) to show the problem.

If you create a second thumbnail, with a different background-size, both the thumbnails have a looping gif!???

Does anyone know why? Is there something wrong with the css? Or is this a bug in Chrome?

Comment: This seems fine if you remove the background-**position** change. Then again, if the position change is in % and not px, again, it's fine - https://jsfiddle.net/hL2boada/12/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hL2boada/14/

Comment: There is still an issue when using only '%'! :( https://jsfiddle.net/tomvanrossom/hL2boada/15/

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/hL2boada/11/

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case the following fixes the bug:

```
background-position: center;
```

It seems to be the Chrome issue since I faced the similar problem when background GIF's stopped working in Chrome a few days ago.

It looks like they have made a lot of changes regarding background rendering in [this release](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/55.0.2859.0..55.0.2868.3?pretty=fuller&n=10000).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing using the following code. Its working fine in Chrome, FF and IE

CSS

```
.thumbnail {
  background-position: -12px -14px;
  background-size: 150%;
  background-color: rgb(250, 252, 252);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(116, 200, 184);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(83, 181, 161);
  cursor: auto;
  display: block;
  filter: none;
  font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 142px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 12px;
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 142px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span><img class="thumbnail" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/xTiTnxd70rHICWIQSs/giphy.gif"></span>
```

Try this out : https://jsfiddle.net/hL2boada/11/